# Re-ordered a nested sorted-map with Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have this sorted map:

```
 (def my-map {1 {:foo "String_1" :ordnen 5 } 
              2 {:foo "String_2" :ordnen 4} 
              3 {:foo "String_3" :ordnen 3} 
              4 {:foo "String_4" :ordnen 1} })
```

And I need to re-ordered it in an ascendant way using the value kept in the **:ordnen** keyword. So, the final sorted-map would be like:

```
  {4 {:foo "String_4" :ordnen 1}
   3 {:foo "String_3" :ordnen 3}
   2 {:foo "String_2" :ordnen 4} 
   1 {:foo "String_1" :ordnen 5 }}
```

I tried:

```
(into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2] (compare (:ordnen key1) (:ordnen key2)))) my-map)
```

but I don't understand how to get and compare the value of **:ordnen** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the value out of the map by calling `val`, and then on the resultant submap, just pull out the value corresponding to `:ordnen` via keyword:

```
(sort-by (comp :ordnen val) my-map)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, short and concise. Just a little nitpick, op stated he want's a sorted map, but  this gives you a sequence of vectors.

Comment: Sorted map:

           (into {} (sort-by (comp :ordnen val) my-map))

Comment: You can also supply a comparator as a second argument to sort-by. Say you wanted to sort :ordnen in descending fashion. (into (sorted-map) (sort-by (comp :ordnen val) > my-map))

Answer (score 3):

Correct way

```
(into
 (sorted-map-by
  (fn [key1 key2]
    (compare
     [(get-in my-map [key1 :ordnen]) key1]
     [(get-in my-map [key2 :ordnen]) key2])))
 my-map)
```

So you want to sort by value. In your case the value is the map, and then you need to sort by the value of the :ordnen key in that map. (get-in my-map [key :ordnen]) is the value you want to sort by, but you need to make sure that the comparator works on unique values. So we make a vector of the value and the key.

**The above approach that Taylor suggests won't work on nonunique values. I added another ordnen 4 entry.**

```
(def my-map {1 {:foo "String_1" :ordnen 5}
             2 {:foo "String_2" :ordnen 4}
             3 {:foo "String_2" :ordnen 4}
             4 {:foo "String_3" :ordnen 3}
             5 {:foo "String_4" :ordnen 1}})


(into (sorted-map-by
       (fn [key1 key2]
         (compare (:ordnen (get my-map key1))
                  (:ordnen (get my-map key2)))))
      my-map)
```

Map entry with key 3 is missing.

```
{5 {:foo "String_4", :ordnen 1}, 4 {:foo "String_3", :ordnen 3}, 2 {:foo "String_2", :ordnen 4}, 1 {:foo "String_1", :ordnen 5}}
```

Comment: Thx, question: why:  " [(get-in my-map [key1 :ordnen]) key1]" and not just "(get-in my-map [key1 :ordnen])"   ?

Comment: Because of the way sorted-map-by works under the hood.  If any keys supplied to compare are  equal, they are handled as if by repeated uses of assoc when building the resulting sorted map.  So here is a potential for data loss.  For example if you do (-> {} (assoc :a 1) (assoc :a 2)), value 1 at :a will get overwritten with 2. We make sure that the arguments to compare are unique, so we use vector pairs with :ordnen value and key of the map entry (key1 and key2 are guaranteed to be unique, so  [ordnen-val key1] and [ordnen-val key2] are also unique.